How to fix an error "Sandbox mode not allowed" in Vercel?
I try to deploy a movie streaming on the Vercel app. While testing it on Firefox (normal mode), there's a message that appears, "Sandbox mode is not allowed!". But when I tried on Firefox (protected mode), the movie appeared and was playing. My framework used on Vercel is Vite. I don't know if I need to reconfigure my repo or what framework I need to use.
screenshot
I try to add vercel.json and put the code on it. But still the message appeared, "Sandbox mode is not allowed!".
{
    "rewrites": [
        {"source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/"}
    ]
}


If it works in one browser, and not in another, it surely indicates the browser may be interfering with what you get from the server.
The error message suggests the app is attempting to exit the browser's 'sandbox' for some reason.
